# Visual Studio: Failed update

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a problem of installing Visual Studio Service Pack 1. Error Code 13EC.

any help?

Comment: Version ?? Operating System ? More info

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happened to me when I was running low on disk space for C:.  Clear off some junk and try it again.

Comment: Yes, this helps. Service pack requires about 5 GB of free space during installation - I don't know why.

Comment: Probably because it unzips some data and uses it to perform the installation.

Answer (score 20):

Just had the same error when trying to install VS2010 SP1 via Windows Update. I had 57GB of free space on drive C: (and more on the other drive).

When I installed it using the installer, it worked fine: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

**EDIT:** I had the same problem with later versions of Visual Studio (Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio 2013), when trying to install Service Packs (SP2, SP3). Using the installer, it installed without problems.

Comment: Maybe, this solution should accept too. Solved! , Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error with the installation of the *Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1*, and yes, it indicates that you need more space on your drive.

I liberated significant space on my drive by temporarily disabling Windows's Hibernate feature. Use `powercfg -H OFF` (as an Administrator, of course) to disable the Hibernate feature (delete the **hiberfil.sys** file). Use `powercfg -H ON` to restore the feature.